# Implicitly kill background processes connected to a foreground process

Tags: bash, shell, unix, background-process, kill

In Bash, I start a number of processes run in the background and have Bash wait in the foreground:

```
sleep 7 & sleep 10 & wait
```

(This is actually a simplification of what `npm script` does, which is the application of this question.)

Then, whenever I `Ctrl+C` out of the `wait` process, I would like all background processes killed.

Is this possible at all? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background processes are child processes of the shell, but not child processes of `wait`, so there is no good way to propagate a signal to `wait` to any of the other processes.

A quick and dirty way to kill all background processes, which you can put into a script or an alias, is

<strike>`kill -INT $(jobs -l | awk '{print $2}')`</strike>

```
kill -INT $(jobs -p)
```

Comment: `jobs -p` lists *just* the process ids, no need for `awk`.